# Tomcat v8.5 não inicializa, apresenta o erro: A child container failed during start

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2.2, cdi, primefaces-5.2

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade, um crud simples com JSF2, Hibernate, Primefaces e CDI. Porem no momento que vou inicializar o projeto no Tomcat tenho o seguinte erro:

```
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TrabalhoFaculdade]]
```

---

Segue log completo do erro:

> ```
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
> ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TrabalhoFaculdade' did not find a matching property.
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Aug 2 2017 21:35:49 UTC
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.5.20.0
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Linux
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            4.9.0-3-amd64
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-oracle/jre
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/christiano/Documentos/Trabalho/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/christiano/apache-tomcat-8.5.20
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/christiano/Documentos/Trabalho/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/christiano/apache-tomcat-8.5.20
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/christiano/Documentos/Trabalho/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/christiano/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/endorsed
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
> INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
> INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
> INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
> INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
> INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
> INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 1837 ms
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
> INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
> INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
> GRAVE: A child container failed during start
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TrabalhoFaculdade]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TrabalhoFaculdade]]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     ... 6 more
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@28578a16]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4860)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4992)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@4acd9788]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:721)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>     at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>     ... 12 more
> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
>     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>     at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
>     at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
>     ... 13 more
>
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
> GRAVE: A child container failed during start
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
> GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more
>
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
> INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
> INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
> INFORMAÇÕES: Stopping service [Catalina]
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
> INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> ago 27, 2017 1:53:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
> INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
> ```

Será que alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Segue o pom.xml:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.TrabalhoFaculdade</groupId>
        <artifactId>TrabalhoFaculdade</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.9.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Isso está parecendo projeto desconfigurado no Eclipse. Você por acaso está usando o Maven?

Comment: romarcio, sim, estou usando Maven, estou aprendendo agora. como faço pra configurar?

Comment: Vou responder como "resposta" já que vou postar um trecho de código.

Answer (score 1):

O erro na verdade é mais embaixo:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
    ... 13 more
```

Como você está utilizando o Maven, as vezes (muito dependendo da rede e situações adversas), um JAR do seu artifactory local pode vir quebrado (alguns bytes foram corrompidos durante a transferência do repositório remoto).

Uma dica para descobrir qual JAR está apresentando problemas:

1. Adicionar um breakpoint na classe `JarFile.java:425` (linha 425)
2. Caindo no breakpoint apresentando problema, na classe pai `ZipFile` você pode conferir o nome através da propriedade `name`

Para forçar o download do artefato novamente, você deve ir ao ser artifactory local, deletar a pasta relacionada ao artefato, e realizar o build do projeto novamente (`clean install`).

Caso esta abordagem não funcione, o JAR ainda apresente problemas, você pode instalar o JAR localmente a partir de um artefato. Esta segunda abordagem deve ser utilizada em **ÚLTIMO CASO**, visto que você terá que instalar o JAR também no artifactory da sua empresa geralmente.

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte, deixe que o maven gerencie o projeto e não o eclipse. Para isso, adicione a seguinte configuração no pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Depois de adicionar essa configuração, se necessário, faça um Maven Update. Se ainda não resolver, exclua o projeto do Eclipse. Depois entre na pasta do projeto e remova as pastas e arquivos do Eclipse. Volte a Eclipse e importe o projeto pela opção Maven > Exists Maven Project. Isso deve resolver.

Comment: Romarcio, fiz os procedimentos e o mesmo erro ocorre. adicionei o pom a pergunta, você pode verificar se tem alguma inconsistência?

Comment: Seu pom.xml parece estar ok. Tente limpar o projeto no servidor, lá na aba servidores, na janela abaixo do editor de código fonte do eclipse, clique sobre o servidor e depois em 'clean' ou 'clean project'. Em seguida faça um Maven Update e tente rodar a aplicação.

Comment: Romarcio não funcionou, o engraçado é que o log diz que um conteine filho não carregou, mais não diz qual.

Comment: Puxa, agora não sei mais o que pode ser. Talvez alguma das dependências corrompidas. Tente mudar a versão de cada dependência para ver se muda alguma coisa.

Comment: @romarcio, inclui detalhes para identificar o problema, mas seu último chute foi bem próximo :)